# Chrome tooltips appear too quickly

Tags: google-chrome, delay, tooltip

Since I last updated Chrome, the little hover-triggered tooltips (the ones defined by the `title` attribute) have been appearing way too fast for me, just a split second after I've moved my cursor on top of an element.

For instance, suppose right now I decide to put my cursor on the hyperlink icon atop the area I'm typing in: the options just beneath get hidden by the hover text almost immediately. Obviously this is more of a bother when dealing with pages which use lots of tooltips, or have them on their text and images (I like to follow along with my mouse as I read).

Is there some way I can get a longer delay, like it used to be?